# Google cloud functions replaces double slash in url

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-functions, cors-anywhere

Im trying to deploy [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere) on Google Cloud Functions. Im supposed to provide the url after gcp's link.

It looks like this :

https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/my-function**/http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees**

but it's transformed to :

https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/my-function**/http:/dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees**

All the double slashes after the host are transformed to simple ones.

I tried replacing **req.url** to transform **http:/** to **http://** but still wont work. Maybe this needs to be fixed in the webserver level.

Here's my function in GCP

```
var cors_proxy = require('cors-anywhere').createServer({
  requireHeader: ['origin', 'x-requested-with'],
  removeHeaders: [
    'cookie',
    'cookie2',
  ],
  // See README.md for other options
});

exports.myFunction = (req, res) => {
  req.url = req.url.replace('/my-function/', '/'); // Strip '/my-function' from the front of the URL, else the proxy won't work.

  return cors_proxy.emit('request', req, res);
};
```

Anyone tried to deploy this in a serverless function?

Comment: That is not a legal URL. Look into URL Encoding when you need to add a URL as a query parameter.

Comment: Just use `https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/my-function/dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees` as the URL instead. As the readme at https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere that you linked to in the question states, *“The protocol part of the proxied URI is optional, and defaults to "http". If port 443 is specified, the protocol defaults to "https".”* So if you wanted to proxy `https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees` (https) instead, you’d use the URL `https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/my-function/dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees:443`

Answer (score 0):

You're using `req.url` which contains a normalized version of the request URL. You'll want to use `req.originalUrl` which, as the name suggests, retains the original requested URL. See [Express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.originalUrl) for more info.